# how to download copy of cloud9 sample code in beagle bone

Tags: joyent

today is 27th Dec 2012 and I just got my Beagle Bone board from RS Components. Once I got into the device Cloud9 IDE... I chosed the blinkingleds.js sample AND clicked RUN. It does running and I tried to stop it (running process) , yet the machine refused. Somehow, I saw the Tour button AND upon clicked on this button... the entire source codes under the Cloud9 folder were deleted!

Bingo, I need another copy of the entire files (that used to be available) under the Cloud9 tree/folder in Beagle Bone. How do I get that copy? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Bonescript library with samples is available from http://github.com/jadonk/bonescript. If you can get your BeagleBone on your network and login to a console prompt, you can:

```
cd /var/lib/cloud9
git stash
git pull
```

That should get you to the latest code.

Comment: You'd need to share the internet connection to the USB. Most operating systems provide Internet Connection Sharing. You could also clone the git repo to your computer add a git remote on your BeagleBone and pull from there.